# Parsing Select and Expand failed error while getting singleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get singleValueExtendedProperties through graph api...

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=subject,singleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(PropertyId eq  'String 0x1082 Name PidTagLastVerbExecutionTime'))
```

I have also tried the above api with message id

```
me/messages/{message-id}...
```

Tried this way too...

```
/me/messages/{message-id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x1082')
```

all these shows same error message...

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Parsing Select and Expand failed.",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first property example is just wrong PidTagLastVerbExecutionTime is a documentation reference and has nothing to do with the property itself. The property is a Tagged property (your trying to use it like a named propety) so the correct format is 'DataType Tag' Value. Because PidTagLastVerbExecutionTime is a SystemTime you also have the Datatype wrong in the second example so something like

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime 0x1082')
```

Should work okay

Comment: Hii Glen ,Thanks for the answer I tried these following api's... ```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime 0x1082')```  and  ```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message-id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime 0x1082')``` same error

Comment: Your first example works fine for me in the Graph Explorer, you might want to check with fiddler to see what is actually going to the server there are some client side libraries that can mung the request itself

Comment: This is the escaped version if that helps https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties(%24filter%3did+eq+%27SystemTime+0x1082%27)